# Unable to open a decoded zip file

Tags: java, codec

Hi i have code for decoding a base64 vaule to its orginal.

```
public class Decode {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String base64= "0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAAAAAEAAA/v///wAAAAD+////AAAAABkAAAD///"

        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
        String testFileName = "tmp" +File.separator + "base64.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(testFileName));
        IOUtils.write(bytes, fos);
    }
}
```

the base64 variable is encoded value of a zip file.I am able to decode it back to its orginal format but unable to open the zip file.It shows the file is invalid.Where am i wrong.?Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

format Zip is not Base64, if you want to open a zip file with java code, you can using java.util.zip.ZipInputStream

Comment: i dont want to read it to a java program. I just need verify if i am able to get the exact file before encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your base64-string does not contain the content of a ZIP file. Except for that, you have to close the FileOutputStream (`fis.close()`) when you are finished writing to it, but unless you start with the correct data, you won't write a ZIP file anyway.

Comment: actually the base64 string was too big that it exceeded the size limit here.so just gave it as an example.will try fis.close()

Comment: it doesnt seem to work fos.close(). but am able to open a zip file without encoding.Is there a specific method for zip files? shouldnt i use FileOutputStream?